# Cross-compiling C++ OpenCV from Visual Studio 2013 on Windows to Ubuntu

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu, visual-studio-2013, cross-compiling

I've got a C++ VS2013 solution with 3 projects, using OpenCV 2.4.10, easylogging++ and Dlib libraries. The problem is that our client is now migrating to Linux (Ubuntu Server). I've looked into Cygwin and MinGW and a few questions here on stackoverflow, but I'm still lost as to where I should start. I need this done as soon as possible, so the simpler solution would be best. I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Might be of interest, though would require upgrading to 2015 https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/03/30/visual-c-for-linux-development/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend using cmake build system on ubuntu. Using Opencv and easylogging on ubuntu out of the box could be a matter of minutes. dlib's website also mentions a simple cmake building steps that works on ubuntu.

After you get your libraries up and running, build your code and see if there are any system-dependent functions then google how to standardize them across systems. If your code is already standardized it should run right then and there.

You can then ask about any specific issues you meet on the way.